# How to finish off these python functions for a 'quick Sort'?

Tags: python, sorting, quicksort

These are 2 functions which can work together to sort an array of integers. The function `quickSort` is complete and would work properly if the `partition` function was defined fully. I'm unsure what the rest of the function should be to have an effective functionallity.

```
def quickSort(mylist,start,end):
    if start<end:
        pivotpos = partition(mylist,start,end)
        print("pos",pivotpos)
        quickSort(mylist,start,pivotpos-1)
        print(quickSort(mylist,start,pivotpos-1))
        quickSort(mylist,pivotpos+1,end)
        print(quickSort(mylist,pivotpos+1,end))
def partition(mylist,left,right):
    pivot = mylist[left]
    pivotpos = left
    currentlow,currenthigh=left+1,right
    while currentlow<=currenthigh:
        if mylist[currentlow]<pivot:

        elif mylist[currentlow]==pivot: 

        else: 

    return pivotpos
```

The `partition` function would have to rearrange the list and return the new pivot position.

Comment: can you tag this with 'homework' please

Comment: @jbrown: [The homework tag is now officially deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated). If you feel the OP didn't put enough efforts or could clarify the question, comment, downvote and move on.

Comment: Well, at least the OP attached some code to work with. Maybe he just got stuck with that homework.

Comment: The code is using a Lomuto like partition scheme, but using left instead of right. The [wiki example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Lomuto_partition_scheme) for this could be modified to use the left value (instead of right == high) as the initial pivot, scanning from right to left for values >= pivot. Note the final swap to ideally place the pivot and pivot value somewhere near the middle of the array.

Comment: You might want to consider a [Hoare partition scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme), which is faster. Note that the Hoare partition scheme quick sort calls use pivot (not pivot-1) and pivot + 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the partition function, You have to put every element of the `mylist` which is smaller than the `pivot` to the left, and every element which is bigger to the `right`. We iterate using `currentlow` and if `mylist[currentlow]` is smaller then `pivot` we have to swap them. In the `currenthigh` variable we save the last element's position, which will be swapped if we encounter a value bigger than the pivot. That way we always put elements bigger than `pivot` at the end of the list. I hope You will understand the following code.

```
def quickSort(mylist, start, end):
    if start < end:
        pivotpos = partition(mylist, start, end)
        #print("pos", pivotpos)
        quickSort(mylist, start, pivotpos - 1)
        #print(quickSort(mylist, start, pivotpos - 1))
        quickSort(mylist, pivotpos + 1, end)
        #print(quickSort(mylist, pivotpos + 1, end))


def partition(mylist, left, right):
    pivot = mylist[left]
    pivotpos = left
    currentlow, currenthigh = left + 1, right
    while currentlow <= currenthigh:
        if mylist[currentlow] < pivot:
            mylist[currentlow], mylist[pivotpos] = mylist[pivotpos], mylist[currentlow]
            pivotpos = currentlow
        elif mylist[currentlow] > pivot:
            mylist[currentlow], mylist[currenthigh] = mylist[currenthigh], mylist[currentlow]
            currenthigh = currenthigh - 1
        currentlow = currentlow + 1
    return pivotpos
```

output:

```
>>> from a import quickSort
>>> a = [3223,1,321,2,43,54,65,1]
>>> quickSort(a,0,7)
>>> a
[1, 1, 2, 43, 54, 65, 321, 3223]
```

Comment: This is a worst case scenario quicksort, since partition returns a pivot position == left every time. This is a Lomuto type partition, and normally the pivot position is ideally somewhere near the middle and the last step is to swap one of the lower values with myList[left] so that the pivot value and  pivot position end up somewhere near the middle.